# How do i add Analytics to my existing wso2is? (WSO2 Identity Server)

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Have deployed wso2is deployed on my k8s cluster using the Dockerfile mentioned in the https://github.com/wso2/docker-is/blob/5.7.x/dockerfiles/ubuntu/is-analytics/base/Dockerfile, its working fine.

Now the requirement has changed to have login stats (successful/unsuccessful/ failed attempts etc.) discover the Analytics support is the one use. But i am not quite sure how do i add this module into my Dockerfile?
Can someone list the various steps to install wso2is with analytics.

I have download the wso2is-analytics-5.7.0 zip, but i am not sure what else in the Dockerfile(from the link mentioned above) needs to change  other than the :

"ARG WSO2_SERVER=wso2is-analytics"

Edited: so going once again the wso2is site : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Prerequisites+to+Publish+Statistics

Step 03: Configure Event Publishers , is these all optional? if already have wso2is deployed before?
because it says this "In a fresh WSO2 IS pack, you can view all the event publishers related to WSO2 IS Analytics in the /repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers directory."

Expected Result:
Have a working wso2is with analytics dasboard to track the login  success/failure attempts.

thanks for your support, appreciate it!

Maurya (novice on wso2is)

Answer (score 0):

The latest IS analytics-5.7.0, has different profiles, here, you need the following profiles,

1. Worker - Consume events from IS and process (This is consumed from event publishers in IS side, in the documentation, Step 3 and 4 are optional, that is documented for further understanding and not needed for deployment initially ) 

   [1] https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2is-analytics-worker
2. Dashboard - This is to view the statistics

   [2] https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2is-analytics-dashboard

   [3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Accessing+the+Analytics+Dashboard

Comment: Thanks Niveathika for replying. but i still confused should we deploy wso2is separately and then also have deployements for the wso2is-analytics-base,  wso2is-analytics-dashboard & wso2is-analytics-worker? My intention here is to re-use my wso2is deployment with oracle. Let me know what it the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: WSO2 IS Analytics is based on a separate server, that's why there are multiple docker images. If you want to run both the servers in one VM, you have to create custom docker images. Also, it is not recommended to run them in the same image as who need to allocate higher reources